# Lebesgue-measure function

Tags: measure-theory

We are looking at $\mathbb{R}$ with the Lebesgue-measure. Let $h \colon [0,1] \to \mathbb {R}$ be a measurable function and let $f(x,t) = h(t) \sin (x-t)$. For $x \in \mathbb {R}$ we are looking at $F(x) =$ $\int _{[0,1]} f(x,-)\,d\lambda$  (might not be defined, depending on $h$). Which of these following statements is true?

a. $F$ is defined and continuous on $[0,1]$, without further requirements to $h$.

b. If $h$ is integrable on $[0,1]$, then $F$ is defined and continuous.

c. Let $F$ be defined. If $h$ is not continuous, then $F$ is also not continuous.

I think that a is false and that b and c are true, is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a. False. A counterexample is $h(t) = \frac{1}{t}$ for $t \in (0,1]$ and $h(0)=0$. Then if $x \notin \pi \mathbb{Z}$, then $\sin(x) \neq 0$. Then $\frac{\sin(x-t)}{t} \sim_{t \to 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{t}$ so $F(x)$ is $\mbox{sign}(\sin(x)) \cdot \infty$.

b. True. If $h$ is integrable, then for any $x$, for all $t$, $|h(t)\sin(x-t)| \le |h(t)|$, and for any $t$, $x \mapsto \sin(x-t)$ is continuous, so the dominated convergence theorem yields that $F$ is continuous (you can actually show that $F$ is $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$.

c. False. A trivial counterexample would be $h(t) = 1_{\{0\}}(t)$. $h$ is not continuous but $F = 0$. Another counterexample is $h(t) = 1_{t < \frac{1}{2}}$. Indeed, $F(x) = \displaystyle{\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}} \sin(x-t)dt = \cos\big(x-\frac{1}{2}\big)-\cos(x)$, which is continuous.